# How to add initial velocity to a rigid body object?

Tags: physics

I want to simulate flying knife (rigid body) then it fall down and hit the ground/floor. How to give the knife an initial velocity to make it flying ? I can't find the setting.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's from old post. Is there any better method ? i was thinking for 2.8, it should be a builtin 'initial velocity' parameter inside the rigid body to add initial force rather than manually set position.

Comment: There’s no other method I know of. I think the Rigid Body system is almost identical between Blender 2.79 and 2.8 anyway.