# Using "Rigid Body" for rolling ball. Flat surface. How to push the ball to roll?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

Think of billiards. With some force, a ball can roll on a flat surface. When I had asked a question about calculating rotation for a rolling ball, someone wrote an answer that I should use Rigid Body. But the Rigid Body introduction video was using a slope. I want to roll a ball on a flat surface.

So, if I have an active Rigid-Body ball and a passive Rigid-Body plane, can I push the ball slightly so that it could roll a little bit and stop (like billiards)? Or must I use a slope?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69460/how-can-you-launch-an-object-at-a-specific-velocity-and-angle-outside-of-the-gam  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133808/how-to-add-initial-velocity-to-a-rigid-body-object  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39169/how-can-a-force-be-applied-not-to-the-center-of-a-rigid-body-object-but-to-one

Comment: @batFINGER I followed the top of the two existing answers, and at first I added the locations at frame 1 and 2. The ball did not move from frame 2. Then I moved the second location key frame to frame 20. Now it started to move from frame 20. But the problem is, now I have an unwanted slide animation between frame 1 and 20. But if this is the only way....

Comment: @batFINGER After some thinking, I thought of an workaround. I used another object to hit the ball so that the ball does not have to slide initially. But I wonder what if I want the ball to accelerate on its own (slowly starts rolling but gets faster and faster), like some sort of machine in a Sci-Fi movie... Maybe I will ask about this later.